# What does matrix[x] for different x indicate?

Tags: python, pandas, mnist

While using the MNIST datasetfrom kaggle,i have noticed that all the tutorials use mnist[x] for different values of x to retrieve different pictures.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mnist=pd.read_csv(r"(dir of dataset)").values
img=mnist[1]
img.shape=(28,28)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

My doubt is what `mnist[1]` retrieves,also i have noticed that `mnist[-1]` also works,so that is why i am confused.

Comment: It's just the index of a row of the dataset. Negative indexes count from the end.

Comment: `mnist[1]` is the second row of the CSV file. `mnist[-1]` is the last row.

Comment: This is just ordinary `pandas` array indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, a matrix is just an array of array. Notice the second "array" I mentioned here could be another "matrix".

So your "matrix[x]" simply means the (x+1)th element of your object.

---

In case of the matrix for a dataset, mostly the first dimension of the matrix would be the sample id.

So your "matrix[x]" means the argument array of the (x+1)th sample.

Comment: So matrix[1] world mean the second row?

Comment: @ChandraSangala Yes, if you would like to call that "row" and you will draw your data frame this way. Technically, it is the first dimension of the matrix.